# Access Denied to the action show and role VIEW : show profile sonata-admin-bundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, sonata-admin, sonata

I work on a symfony project and I use SonataAdminBundle with SonataUserBundle and FOSUserBundle.
My problem is that in the backend the show profile of the current account is displayed only to the SUPER_ADMIN but For the ADMIN and REFERENT I have this error :

> Access Denied to the action show and role VIEW

And this is my configuration:

**Security.yml**

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN:
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN
        - ROLE_ADMIN_SITE
        - ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH
        - ROLE_ADMIN_REFERENTS_ALL
        - ROLE_ADMIN_ADHERENTS_ALL
        - ROLE_ADMIN_ADMINS_ALL
    ROLE_ADMIN:
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN
        - ROLE_ADMIN_REFERENTS_ALL
        - ROLE_ADMIN_ADHERENTS_ALL
        - ROLE_ADMIN_VILLES_ALL
        - ROLE_DEVAGNOS_BACKEND_ADMIN_INSCRIT_NEWS_ALL
        - ROLE_DEVAGNOS_BACKEND_ADMIN_CONTACTMAIL_ALL
        - ROLE_ADMIN_PAGE_ALL
        - ROLE_ADMIN_SONDAGE_ALL
        - ROLE_ADMIN_CATEGORIE_ALL
        - ROLE_ADMIN_ARTICLES_ALL
        - ROLE_ADMIN_IMPORTCONTACTS_ALL
        - ROLE_ADMIN_NEWSLETTER_ALL
        - ROLE_ADMIN_COMITECITOYEN_ALL
        - ROLE_ADMIN_ASSOCIATIONSOUTIEN_ALL
        - ROLE_ADMIN_DEMANDE_ALL
        - ROLE_ADMIN_CENTRES_ALL
        - ROLE_ADMIN_EVENT_ALL


    ROLE_REFERENT:
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN
        - ROLE_ADMIN_EVENT_ALL
        - ROLE_ADMIN_SUJET_ALL
        - ROLE_ADMIN_RAPPORT_ALL
```

Someone can help me please ? thanks for all

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using the wrong role identifiers.

Say you have an `EventAdmin` registered as service `app.admin.event`. The correct roles for this admin would be `ROLE_APP_ADMIN_EVENT_{LIST/VIEW/ETC}`.

Comment: All Rols identifiers work fine in my case, except the show profile